# Aggregate search function errors when executed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm clearly not understanding the aggregate function in mongoose. I'm trying to query the productCode field and return all of the products. The code below returns the error;

**Product.aggregate(...).search is not a function.**

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using mongoose.

```
products = await Product.aggregate().search({
    text: {
      query: 'text_supplied',
      path: 'productCode'
    }
  });
```

**Update Date**

The text in the query comes from an input field. I want to return all the documents from the product collection that contain the text I pass from the input field. This is for an autocomplete dropdown on the client-side. For instance.

Text from input field: '1';

Mongodb Collection: `Products`

```
[
  {
    productCode: '1A'
  },
  {
    productCode: 'C1'
  },
  {
    productCode: 'C2'
  }
];
```

In this scenario, I want to return every product that contains '1'. There for it return '1A' and 'C1'

Comment: what is your mongoose version?

Comment: "mongoose": "^5.9.20"

Comment: Try with `await Product.aggregate().search({
    text: {
      query: 'text_supplied',
      path: 'productCode'
    }
  }).exec();`

Comment: Update question with the current problem and make it contain one question.

Answer (score 1):

The atlas search aggregation stage was only added to mongoose for version [5.10.0](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#5100--2020-08-14).

> feat(aggregate): add Aggregate#search() for Atlas Text Search #9115

Regardless according to the use case your posted you don't want to be using a [text](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/text/) but rather you want a [regex](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/regex/#syntax) search:

```
Product.aggregate([
   {
      "$search": {
         "regex": {
            "path": "productCode",
            "query": ".*1.*"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

I could explain further but this was not the original question, however I do recommend you read up some more on [analyzers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/) as their role in both the indexing and querying is pivotal.

Comment: I'm not using Atlas. I think that's why this doesn't work.

Comment: No it doesn't work because your mongoose version needs an upgrade, once you upgrade it you will get a different error saying you don't have an atlas text index which is one of the requirments.

Comment: Sorry, I did update and the error has changed to 'MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$search''

Comment: Atlas search does not work outside of atlas but in this case I'd go with regexp over full text search, thus this is the correct answer.